# undefined value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this function to dynamically create a list from an array

```
function fill1(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var a=arr[i].code;
        var b=arr[i].name;
        out += '<li><a href="" onclick="myfunction(this)" id="'+arr[i].code+'" value="'+arr[i].name+'">' + 
        b + '</a></li>';
    }
    document.getElementById("instrumental").innerHTML = out;
}
```

and this function for alert

```
function myfunction(elem) {
    var x=elem.id;
    var c=document.getElementById(x).value;
    alert(c);
}
```

When I alert x its ok but when i alert c its showing undefined

Comment: An `a` element does not have a `.value` property. Nor is its `value` attribute valid.

Comment: Since `value` is not valid, it becomes a custom attribute.. May be accessed by `getAttribute("value")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting a "value" property on an "a" tag which is not a valid attribute you want to set a "data-value" attribute instead, like so:

```
out += '<li><a href="" onclick="myfunction(this)" id="'+arr[i].code+'" data-value="'+arr[i].name+'">' +
```

These "data-" attributes are a way to allow you to add your own attributes to elements that do not affect how they are rendered by the browser.

You also can't simply access attributes on DOM elements in the way you are attempting, you need to do it like this

```
var c=document.getElementById(x).getAttribute('data-value')
```

Answer (score 0):

**value** is not a valid attribute for tag **a** If you are using HTML you can convert your code to use data attribute